# Ring module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Got peculiar question, not sure if my answer is correct.

Let $R$ be ring and $b,r\in R$

Let also $f_b:R\rightarrow R$ where $f_b(r)=rb$ and $g_b(r)=br$

Why $f_b$ is R-module homomorpism, but $g_b$ not necessarily?

My take is that $f(ax)=a f(x)$, for all $x\in M,a\in R$ so

$f_b(ar)=a f_b(r)=(ar)b=f_b(ar)$ -

$g_b(ar)=a g_b(r)=(ab)r \stackrel{?}{=} g_b(ar)$(it works in commutative ring, but doesnt in case of noncommutative)

Is my take ok, and this trivial answer correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is correct under the implicit assumption that the modules are left-modules. In case $R$ is not  commutative one distinguishes left and right modules. But it appears in your context "module" means "left module." The way you write it up could be imporved though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one hand, we've got

$$g_b(ar) = b(ar)$$

and, on the other hand,

$$a g_b(r) = a(br) = (ab)r$$

Indeed, those values are not guaranteed to be equal if the ring is not commutative, so your assertion is right.